# Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a<b$. Determine $ d_n:= | \{ c\in\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{Z} \ | \ a < c < b \} |$

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces

The assignment is:

> Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a<b$. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ determine $ d_n:= | \{ c\in\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{Z} \  | \ a < c < b \} |$.

Firstly, I began to see what the solution could look like and the result was that
$$d_n = \sum^{-1+b-a}_{k=-1} n + k - 1= \sum^{b-a}_{k=0} n+k-2$$
After looking at some examples the idea was that if $b-a=1$ then $d_n = n-1$ and if $b-a=2$ then $d_n = n-1 + n$. Not sure if this is right though or it helps me at this assignment at all.

I'd really appreciate help.

Comment: Writing $c=t/n$ we see $d_n=\#\{t\in\Bbb Z:na<t<nb\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translate what you're being asked to a more convenient notation. Fix two integers $a<b$. For a fixed $n\in\Bbb Z_+$, we want to know for how many $k\in\Bbb Z$, we have $$a<\frac k n<b$$

This is the same as $$na<k<nb$$

If I give you two integers $a',b'$, can you count for how many integers $k'$ we have $a'<k<b'$?

Comment: $|na - nb| - 1$?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "nicer" notation, just different.

Comment: @JeffSnider I think the notation is nicer, more convenient.